# MySQL SUM function and CASE statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, case

```
SELECT 
    CASE schuleArtID 
        WHEN 1 THEN SUM(schuleSummeSchueler) / 8
        WHEN 2 THEN SUM(schuleSummeSchueler) / 6 * 0.8
        WHEN 3 THEN SUM(schuleSummeSchueler) / 6 * 0.8
        WHEN 4 THEN SUM(schuleSummeSchueler) / 5 * 0.8
        WHEN 5 THEN SUM(schuleSummeSchueler) / 3 * 0.5
        WHEN 6 THEN SUM(schuleSummeSchueler) / 3 * 0.8
    END AS potenzial
FROM 
    sys_theorie_schule
WHERE
    filialID = '311'
GROUP BY
    schuleArtID
```

This works, but now I need a sum because there are multiple rows.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(
        CASE schuleArtID 
            WHEN 1 THEN SUM(schuleSummeSchueler) / 8
            WHEN 2 THEN SUM(schuleSummeSchueler) / 6 * 0.8
            WHEN 3 THEN SUM(schuleSummeSchueler) / 6 * 0.8
            WHEN 4 THEN SUM(schuleSummeSchueler) / 5 * 0.8
            WHEN 5 THEN SUM(schuleSummeSchueler) / 3 * 0.5
            WHEN 6 THEN SUM(schuleSummeSchueler) / 3 * 0.8
        END
    ) AS potenzial
FROM 
    sys_theorie_schule
WHERE
    filialID = '311'
GROUP BY
    schuleArtID
```

Here, I only get the result `[Err] 1111 - Invalid use of group function`.

Here is the structure of the table (Sorry for the German column names):

```
CREATE TABLE `sys_theorie_schule` (
  `schuleID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `filialID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `schuleName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `schuleStrasse` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `schulePlz` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `schuleOrt` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `schuleArtID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `schuleSummeSchueler` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `schuleEntfernung` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `online` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`schuleID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

MySQL-Version: 5.0.51a-24+lenny5

Could somebody help, please?
Many thanks!

Comment: Rewrite your question in english.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(
        CASE schuleArtID 
            WHEN 1 THEN schuleSummeSchueler / 8
            WHEN 2 THEN schuleSummeSchueler / 6 * 0.8
            WHEN 3 THEN schuleSummeSchueler / 6 * 0.8
            WHEN 4 THEN schuleSummeSchueler / 5 * 0.8
            WHEN 5 THEN schuleSummeSchueler / 3 * 0.5
            WHEN 6 THEN schuleSummeSchueler / 3 * 0.8
        END
    ) AS potenzial
FROM 
    sys_theorie_schule
WHERE
    filialID = '311'
```

You can't sum an expression that already includes a sum, and there is no point in grouping by `schuleArtID` when you want a grand total.

Comment: @Fakerhardcore What "same"? There is no `GROUP BY` now. So, the error message must be different.

Comment: @FractalizeR It's exactly the same error `"[Err] 1111 - Invalid use of group function"` i'm also confused.

Comment: @Fakerhardcore Post `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for your table, please.

Comment: @FractalizeR I've added it to my post

Comment: @Fakerhardcore: I have just tried it on SQLFiddle, and this query runs without errors: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/209b5/1

Comment: @Mark Bannister SQLFiddle uses MysqlVersion 5.5.20 that could be the reason or? Would be interesting to know which version I need at least.
I ask my provider what he can do.

Comment: @Fakerhardcore: It's unlikely to be the reason - I would expect this query to work on any RDBMS (with the equivalent schema set up); it is all standard SQL.

Comment: @Fakerhardcore I also tried it on my local MySQL 5.5.16. It works without problems. What version do you have?